# Calling Function from Separate File Loops When User Inputs Incorrect Data Type

Tags: c++, function

I have a problem with a function that I am attempting to use in my main.cpp file. It is called getFloat and simply enough gets a float from the user, but when the user inputs a non-float value (e.g. "Thomas Harding"), the program gets stuck at cin even though I have my usual protections against this type of problem (cin.ignore(100, '\n'; cin.clear();, etc.)

I think the problem has something to do with the value being referenced with the ampersand...the function is trying to return a non-float value to a float type in another file. My work looks like this:

[from main.cpp]

```
#include "getFloat.hpp"
...
...
...
...
...
...
getFloat(load);
```

[in getFloat.cpp]

```
void getFloat(float &value)
{
   cin >> value;
   while (cin.fail())
   {
      cin.clear();
      cin >> value;
      cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
   }
}
```

Can anybody see why this gets stuck at the cin statement when I input non-numeric values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `cin.ignore()` before you attempt to read input again.  I.e.

```
  cin.clear();
  cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
  cin >> value;
```

Comment: @KhanKhuu Can't upvote? weird. In another few minutes you should be able to mark this answer as the Chosen Answer, favored by the Giver Of Data. In the meantime, I'll take care of the upvote.